# Understanding scipy nnls output

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to understand the output from nnls in scipy:
The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import nnls
A = np.array([[30, 120, 90],[60, 90, 120]])
b = np.array([67.5, 60])
x, rnorm = nnls(A,b)
print x, rnorm
```

## Output is:

## [ 0.          0.42857143  0.17857143] 0.0

Comment: The official documentation is at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html , can you edit to specify what question you have that is not covered there?

Comment: I want to know what the each element of solution vector specifies?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of x is context dependent. I.e. if you are doing polynomial least squares it will be the coefficients in the polynomial. In general is the solution to though it is the value of x that satisfies the minimization problem found at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html.

`argmin_x || Ax - b ||_2 such that x>=0.`

as for `rnorm` it is the residual norm which is equal to `||Ax - b||_2`. It's a way of measuring the error between the actual solution and the approximation.